# Why do I see boolean operators used on arrays or functions?

Tags: javascript

In many projects I commonly see OR or AND boolean operators being used on arrays or objects. What does this return? Why do developers do this? And is this acceptable as clean code?

EDIT:

Example:

```
var foo = foo || [];
```

Comment: Can you give an example? People are _probably_ relying on what effectively amounts to a boolean conversion, but [I'll leave whether that's a good idea up to you...](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/assets/tygr_0401.png)

Comment: That's okay in JavaScript. If the first is falsey the second value is used. That's not a boolean operator. It's an or operator.

Comment: I was asking for specific behavior with non-primitive types, i already know how the || operator works with primitive types.